# Apache Redirect A record to different URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, passenger

I have been researching this for the last couple days with no success. I'm running Passenger Gem / Apache / Rails in production. I'm cutting over some old services and would like to re-direct an A record (http://webmail.domain.com) to a completely different server / URL (https://mail.domain.com/webmail.)

Here is my VirtualHost config in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName webmail.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://mail.domain.com/webmail
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried `< VirtualHost *:80>` but i get a warning when I restart the apache service.

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

As you can tell I'm really new to Apache so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the .htaccess file in the root of webmail.domain.com

```
Redirect http://webmail.domain.com https://mail.domain.com/webmail
```

Comment: Guess I still need a little more explanation. How do you create a root record in apache for http://webmail.domain.com? Is it a VirtualHost with a ServerAlias and DocumentRoot? I tried several things and was unable to get it to work.

Comment: @prodigerati is webmail.domain.com a real website? Does it have a web root with files etc like a normal site or is it just an alias in DNS?

Comment: Just an alias in DNS, sorry should have said that to begin with.